# randomly assign condition replicates to other rows of data R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame that is similar to this example data.frame:

```
sample <- paste("sample", seq(1:36), sep="_")
metadata = data.frame(sample = sample, treatment = c(rep("Control",9), rep("Control",3), rep("Treat1",3), rep("Treat2",3), rep("Control",9), rep("Control",3), rep("Treat1",3), rep("Treat2",3)), time =c( rep("T0",9), rep("T1",3),  rep("T1",3), rep("T1",3), rep("T0",9), rep("T1",3),  rep("T1",3), rep("T1",3)), city =c(rep("city1",18),rep("city2",18)))
```

I need that 3 replicates from Treat 1 and 3 from Treat2 of T1 are randomly assign to the rows of the control T0.
How could I do that?
Thanks!

Comment: Just to specify what you ask: do you want 3+3 different replicates for each sample (6 control replicates for sample_1, another 6 replicates for sample 2...)?

Comment: Thanks, I just need that instead of having 9 control replicates of control, I assign 3 replicates of treat1 and treat2 to time T0, without changing the sample names, I just need the conditions to be re-assigned in order to have 3 control, 3 Treat1 and 3 treat2